# Run Angular 2 application with Tomcat

Tags: java, angular, tomcat, spark-java

I have a backend which uses Spark-java framework in order to generate the routes and access to the server side. I was using AngularJS which worked well because it was all javascript and the files were executed well. Now I decided to go for Angular, but the problem is that I can't load the angular files.

The client side with typescript works well when I run ng serve, but doing that I can't access the backend.

Is possible to execute an angular 2 application with tomcat? Or what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Use `ng build [--prod]`, put all the files under dist in your war file, deploy the war file. A built angular app is just a set of static files. Any web server can serve static files.

Comment: I don't see how it's related to the change from AngularJS to Angular 2. Angular is a frontend framework. Serve these files correctly (regardless their content) and they will work (if the content is working).

Answer (score 0):

First of all. After your run `ng build`, it compiling your `typescript` code to `javascript` so it's doesn't matter for `Spark` that you use `Angular2` or `AngularJS`.

Did you configure `(maven/gradle)`to put your built webapp files under `resources/public` directory and put `staticFileLocation("/public");` in your `Main` backend class to tell `Spark` where to seek webapp files?

If not you can manually run `ng build` and copy your `target/dist` content to `resources/public` directory. It should help.

*If you use `win` try to run your `IDE` as administration.